# Using Nginx with Wordpress to perform a non-template URLs redirections

Tags: database, wordpress, nginx, redirect

#### The Case

We have 2 websites, each website has a different URL structure:

- `www.domain1.com/category/sub-category/`**`post-id`**`/slug`
- `www.domain2.net/category/sub-category/`**`yyyy/mm/dd`**`/slug`

Each website has a separate CMS (Java-based), a separate database (Postgres), and separate storage (Amazon S3).

#### The Plan

We are going to have one multisite CMS (WordPress) that serves the 2 previous websites, with one database (MySQL), and one storage.
All of that has been done and we are in the final stages: migration has been done from the old database to one new WordPress database, the Amazone buckets have been merged into one new bucket, and the multisite functionality works fine.

#### The Problem

We want to adopt the 2nd website's URL structure and use it for both sites, so all the new URLs will have this structure:

- `www.domain1.com/category/sub-category/`**`yyyy/mm/dd`**`/slug`
- `www.domain2.net/category/sub-category/`**`yyyy/mm/dd`**`/slug`

Our concern is about the old URLs of the 1st website which are already shared on social media and used by other websites, How to redirect the old structure URLs to the new one, there's no way to get the `yyyy`, `mm`, or `dd` from the old URLs, we need to inquiry that from the database using the legacy id of the post.

#### An Idea

I had an idea that we can create a table (could be an Amazon DynamoDB table or Redis) with 2 columns: `legacy-id`, and `new-url`, so I will pre-populate the new URLs based on the legacy IDs to prevent overloading the database with many inquiries such as these to get the new URLs.

BUT, is there a way to link Nginx with this table, so Nginx will extract the `post-id` from the old URL and use that table to get the `new-url` based on the extracted `post-id`.

Any help on this guys?

Answer (score 0):

I think dynamic rewrite based on the data in Redis is possible using embedded Lua.

Check these two links: [Lua module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module), [Lua Redis driver](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis)

Another solution is to write the redirect logic using the language of your choice with some web-server for that language and then use [proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) nginx directive to proxy your requests to that web-server.